# Does activation energy depend on steric factors?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, energy

I thought that activation energy depends on steric factors.
By Arrhenius equation it must depend on steric factors since $A$ depends on steric factors. $$k=A\cdot\mathrm e^{-\frac{E_\mathrm a}{RT}}$$ (for bimolecular reaction)

But my book says it doesn’t.

Does it depend on steric factors or not and why?

Answer (score 1):

The Arrhenius model of a rate rate constant is very basic so has to be modified in many cases. One of these is when steric factors (generally undefined exactly) are used as an empirical  multiplier to A and used as a rationale to fit experimental data.